# How to hide a group name in a kendo grid, so it is not displayed on each row?

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that displays grouped data.

Every row in that grid displays a group name and a data in that group:

[image]

I do not want to display Section/Group name on each row.
and instead of `Section: Group Name`, I just want to display `Group Name`

So, instead of `Section: Incoming Report Totals`, I want to display `Incoming Report Totals`

This is my grid definition:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ReportPropertyEntityList)
                        .Name("ReportPropertyGrid")
                        .Columns
                        (
                            columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(c => c.ReportGroup).Title("Section");
                                columns.Bound(c => c.PropertyName).Title("Report Name");
                            }
                        )
                        .Scrollable(s => s.Height("auto").Virtual(true).Enabled(true))
                        .Selectable(stb => stb.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
                        .Reorderable(reorderable => reorderable.Columns(true))
                        .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
                        .Sortable()
                        .ColumnMenu(b => b.Enabled(true))
                        .Pageable(p => p
                                .Refresh(true)
                                .PageSizes(false)
                        )
                          .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu)
                            .Extra(false)
                            .Operators(operators => operators
                                .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                                    .Contains("Contains")
                                    .IsEqualTo("EqualTo")
                                    .IsNotEqualTo("NotEqualTo")
                                    .IsEmpty("Empty"))))
                          .DataSource(ds => ds
                               .Ajax()
                               .Group(g => g.Add(p => p.ReportGroup))
                               .PageSize(5)
                               .Events(e => e.Error("CheckError"))
                              .Read(read => read.Action("GetReportPropertyData", "ReportProperty", new {reportID = ViewBag.ReportID, ticketID = ViewBag.TicketID }))
                          )

)
```

How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(c => c.ReportGroup).Title("Section"). 
                                .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#=value#");
                                columns.Bound(c => c.PropertyName).Title("Report Name");
                            }
```

You can hide grouping column in the Grid's dataBound event.add following to grid:

```
 .Events(events => events
                          .DataBound("onDataBound")


                      )
```

and add following script to page:

```
<script>
    function onDataBound(arg) {
        console.log("Grid data bound");
        var grouptedColumns = $(".k-group-indicator").attr("data-field");
        var grid = $("#ReportPropertyGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        if (grouptedColumns) {
            grid.hideColumn(grouptedColumns);
        } else {
            var columns = grid.getOptions().columns;
            columns.forEach(function (me) {
                if (me.hidden !== undefined && me.hidden === true) {
                    grid.showColumn(me.field);
                }
           });
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank's, man. It makes it to display `Section: Group Name`. But what if I do not want to repeat Section/Group name on each row? How to keep it only on the header row for the group?